# Netflix not working; video loads indefinitely

Tags: 14.04, video, google-chrome

Is anyone else experiencing issues with Netflix on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Chrome version 46). I can navigate the site just fine but when I try to play videos I just get the red loading circle indefinitely. Internet works, all other sites work, other video playback works. I'm at a loss for what could be going on. In the console i get the following error during video playback

Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Rejected with system code (33)

Comment: works fine here - Version 46.0.2490.86 (64-bit)

Comment: I switched from google chrome stable to unstable and now it works just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey so I finally figured out how to fix this. I just cleared my chrome settings with

`sudo rm -r ~/.config/google-chrome`

this resets all chrome settings and configurations as if it were a fresh install